# How to have two XAML files with only one code behind file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-4.0

I want to have two XAML file (Window) having a single code behind file(filename.xaml.cs) in my WPF application.

Comment: I don't it is possible (maybe try to inherit codebehind classess). If you would use MVVM pattern, could be much easier.

Comment: Not possible for any sort of compiled XAML file; both the .xaml and .xaml.cs files must declare the class name, so if you used the same code-behind, the names would not match up.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve with this?

Comment: If you think both XAML files will share same functionality then create a common ViewModel or use PRISM MVVM framework

Comment: Like on button click event on two window views I don't have to write two event funtions having same functionality.

Comment: Great example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Btw, go for MVVM as @Senthil suggests.

Answer (score 1):

A code behind file corresponds to a single root element in XAML, so its not possible to have 2 files share a single code behind file.

That being said, you can often accomplish the underlying goals via other techniques, including:

1. Use a `UserControl` for "child" content, and include the control directly in the main XAML file.
2. Use [merged resource dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178(v=vs.110).aspx) to separate out resources/styles